# Does Google Chrome's message "A data breach on a site or app exposed your password" indicates a vulnerability in my webpage?

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, security, web, browser

I have a website with typical login page, however when i login to the website with specific credentials, the Google Chrome's message "A data breach on a site or app exposed your password. Chrome recommends checking your saved passwords now";

Does this message indicates that there's a vulnerability in my login page in which enabled hackers to breach my password, and accordingly shall change some code regarding the functionality of my webpage, or does it indicate something different am unaware of, as after a research on the following [link](https://security.googleblog.com/2019/12/better-password-protections-in-chrome.html) there's apparently other aspects Google Chrome takes into consideration prior to displaying this message.

Please Advise,
Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 2):

This Chrome functionality is advising the users to change their password as the password being used may have been compromised or leaked in previous data breaches.

According to this [link](https://security.googleblog.com/2019/12/better-password-protections-in-chrome.html), Google "compares passwords and usernames against over 4 billion credentials that Google knows to have been compromised". It is not related to vulnerabilities with your login page.